# Install p5i package on opensolaris 5.11 snv_110

Tags: opensolaris

I inherited an opensolaris server and we need to install a nice new network card (pci id 8086,10fb).  The  ixgbe package recently added support for this card; so I wanted to upgrade to the following.

http://pkg.opensolaris.org/dev/en/search.shtml?token=ixgbe&action=Search

Problem:  How do install these packages?

The server is headless.  I can forward an X display, but what program to start?  The "install" link doesn't invoke any package manager when I run firefox on the server...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could run

$ pfexec pkg install SUNWixgbe

Running with display, you should click on the p5i link from your browser to install it. This feature was made out in OpenSolaris 2009.06, which is snv_111. It may not be supported on snv_110, so you need to upgrade to the latest:

$ pfexec pkg image-update

This will create a new boot environment (most likely it'll be 'opensolaris-1' in the GRUB). You will be able to roll back any changes if required just by booting into your old installation.

Comment: yes...  The pkg command is nowhere to be found on this machine.  Is it new with snv_111?  The old tools (e.g. pkgadd) work just fine.

Comment: That's weird. pkg util seems to be available even in 2008.11:

http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2008.11/getstart/upgrade.html

Isn't in it missing from your PATH?

Comment: http://opensolaris.org/sc/src/pkg/gate/src/man/pkg.1.txt

The online manpage indicates I should have /usr/bin/pkg.  No such file exists.  Any way to install it with pkgadd?  Thanks.

P.S. The dev site makes pkg sound very beta-ish.  :(

Comment: Seems like the previous admin removed it completely (any idea why?) The package is called SUNWipkg, I couldn't find the download link, maybe you will succeed. The current solution is to build it from source, this link may help you:
http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=250798